# New to sqlite3, how do I execute .sql code on .db3 files?

Tags: sqlite

Very basic question, having a hard time finding an explanation online.

I have a file code.sql that can be run on two different databases, a.db3 and b.db3.  I used sqlite a.db3 to open the database in sqlite3.  How do I run code.sql on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `.read code.sql` command, or call `sqlite3` with the file as input: `sqlite3 a.db3 < code.sql`.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are trying to use the sqlite3 command line tool that you can dowload from the sqlite.org website.

I recomend that you use, instead, sqlitestudio http://sqlitestudio.one.pl

This has a [feature](http://sqlitestudio.one.pl/docs/html/manual.html#__RefHeading__2285_346829139) to execute SQL from a file on a database:

Answer (score 0):

Use DB Browser for SQLite is a high quality, visual, open source tool to create, design, and edit database files compatible with SQLite.

You can download the DB Browser at SQLite https://sqlitebrowser.org/